# We will get married as soon as we have ..... the problem of where we are going to live

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

This is a test question. I cannot figure out why I should prefer one or another.

> We will get married as soon as we have ..... the problem of where we
>   are going to live.
>
> 1. resolved
> 2. settled

Comment: Check out sense 2 of *settle* (yours is sense 1): http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/settle.

Comment: Is resolve  wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to prefer one over the other? _We will get married as soon as we have resolved and settled the problem of where we are going to live_.

Comment: Your recent questions are similar: choosing the word that best completes the text. You can try to argue with the exercise, but you will miss the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, there is a problem (where we are going to live), but not a dispute.
The statement does not indicate any difference (dispute) regarding the location. Maybe they agree as to where to live, but can't find an available house.

So I would use:

> We will get married as soon as we have **resolved** the problem of where we are going to live.

Answer (score 0):

Both the verbs settle and resolve are interchangeable if used in the sense of finding a solution to or solving a dispute or problem. So you can use  either of them, without any difference in meaning.

Look up the verb settle in The Free Dictionary under the heading Translation entry # 1.  Settle = resolve (a dispute or problem).

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/settle